# ISSUES USING AS7265X SPECTRAL SENSOR WITH SPARKFUN ESP32-S2 THING PLUS

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32, sparkfun

So I have connected a SparkFun Triad Spectroscopy Sensor - AS7265x (Qwiic) to my SparkFun Thing Plus - ESP32-S2 WROOM using a Qwiic cable. I loaded the example code and I am only getting zeros from the sensors... No error, it throws a connection error when disconnected, just this image as the output over the serial monitor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ySj.jpg

```html
/*
  Read the 18 channels of spectral light over I2C using the Spectral Triad
  By: Nathan Seidle
  SparkFun Electronics
  Date: October 25th, 2018
  License: MIT. See license file for more information but you can
  basically do whatever you want with this code.

  This example takes all 18 readings and blinks the illumination LEDs 
  as it goes. We recommend you point the Triad away from your eyes, the LEDs are *bright*.
  
  Feel like supporting open source hardware?
  Buy a board from SparkFun! https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15050

  Hardware Connections:
  Plug a Qwiic cable into the Spectral Triad and a BlackBoard
  If you don't have a platform with a Qwiic connection use the SparkFun Qwiic Breadboard Jumper (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14425)
  Open the serial monitor at 115200 baud to see the output
*/

#include "SparkFun_AS7265X.h" //Click here to get the library: http://librarymanager/All#SparkFun_AS7265X
AS7265X sensor;

#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("AS7265x Spectral Triad Example");

  Serial.println("Point the Triad away and press a key to begin with illumination...");
  while (Serial.available() == false)
  {
  }              //Do nothing while we wait for user to press a key
  Serial.read(); //Throw away the user's button

  if (sensor.begin() == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Sensor does not appear to be connected. Please check wiring. Freezing...");
    while (1)
      ;
  }

  sensor.disableIndicator(); //Turn off the blue status LED

  Serial.println("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,R,I,S,J,T,U,V,W,K,L");
}

void loop()
{
  sensor.takeMeasurementsWithBulb(); //This is a hard wait while all 18 channels are measured

  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedA()); //410nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedB()); //435nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedC()); //460nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedD()); //485nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedE()); //510nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedF()); //535nm
  Serial.print(",");

  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedG()); //560nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedH()); //585nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedR()); //610nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedI()); //645nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedS()); //680nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedJ()); //705nm
  Serial.print(",");

  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedT()); //730nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedU()); //760nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedV()); //810nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedW()); //860nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedK()); //900nm
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensor.getCalibratedL()); //940nm
  Serial.print(",");

  Serial.println();
}
```

I have run the Example "GetVersion" With this output:
AS7265x Spectral Triad Example
AMS Device Type: 0x40
AMS Hardware Version: 0x41
Major Firmware Version: 0xC
Patch Firmware Version: 0x0
Build Firmware Version: 0x0

I just tested using an arduino nano connected over i2c again. Same result as the esp32's all zeros on output in serial. Im at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

This was an environment issue. Ran arduino as portable and fixed....